# datagridview retrieve user input C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in C# and I want to get the values that the user input in the DataGridView but it always gives Null and the DataGridView is not capturing the user input

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFEhL.png)

Comment: Can you give some more information how your UI looks like and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: actually I have a form of invoice, the end user will come and insert the itemcode and the description and cost of the item, it could be more than one item. so I choosed to have the inputs in a gridview

Comment: Can you show the UI and in which event you are trying to capture the information

Comment: I have added the picture and I am trying to capture that in RowEnter

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Row enter is actually triggered when it enters the row have you tried in cell leave?

Comment: Your cursor is on a new row, so the cell you are checking doesn't have a value yet.  It's null.  Check for that before trying to access it.

Comment: I tried in cell leave and it still giving me the same thing

Comment: @Mohammed: Try adding your code to the CellValueChanged Event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint after the user input and check if the data dataGridView1 contains your data. It seems like your data is not saved into your dataGridView correctly.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: @Developer I can't post a comment unless i've earned 50 reputation :(

Comment: @Mohammed that means that your table is empty and you should check the way you handle the user input. How do you save the inout to your datagridview?

Comment: you mean that there is a way to save the data to the datagridview?! I do not know how to do that actually

Comment: try this: `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value`. Usually you use bindings. Check [this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)